# Using DATETIME SQL datatype, especially with DEFAULT and ON UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, mysql-workbench

W3schools defines the DATETIME datatype thusly:

> A date and time combination. Format: YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss. The
> supported range is from '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31
> 23:59:59'. Adding DEFAULT and ON UPDATE in the column definition to
> get automatic initialization and updating to the current date and time

So, I'm trying to create a table that will record the date of each record inserted.  I'm trying to record down to the minute, but not the second.  I've tried to create the table as such:

```
    create table forum(
postID int(2) AUTO_INCREMENT,
primary key (postID),
title varchar(100),
content varchar(2000),
postTime DATETIME(YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm) DEFAULT ON UPDATE
)
```

But that produces a syntax error.  I've tried modifying it in countless ways, but short of

```
create table forum(
postID int(2) AUTO_INCREMENT,
primary key (postID),
title varchar(100),
content varchar(2000),
postTime DATETIME
)
```

nothing seems to be palatable to MySQL workbench.  How can I properly express what I'm trying to do?

Comment: In general, prefer the mysql documentation rather than other resources : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: Thanks, I figured if there was some kind of official documentation I would have come up after googling the question.  I guess I was wrong.